# Quicker way to access element in a large array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, runtime

My program's runtime is taking a while when I do: array[index]
I believe this is because "array" is a very large array and it takes a while for the array to load. Is there any way to go through the array as its loading, and once "index" is found, it stops loading?

My theory is that you must wait for the whole array to load before you go through it, but I'm unsure if there's another way (I also thought about mapping and pointers, but that seems to be the same problem)

Any ideas on how to make my runtime faster with a large array?

Edit: Code for my question:

```js
function myFunction(index) {
  array = ["702-123-456", "702-234-567",...] 
  return array[index]; 
}
```

where there are 2000 phone numbers. Once array[index] (the index can change as index is being passed into a function) is found, the number is returned.

Comment: Well, I donot think you can have a control on loading a array into RAM. This needs to be taken care by OS and once done then only you can access array. Maybe breaking the arrray logically into multiple ones may help you out. Or you can also rethink on the data structure used.

Comment: I see. Do you think its the same problem if I sliced the array, because I would need to wait for the array to load then slice it? While I think the problem is that I have to wait for the array to load, which is causing a long runtime, I am unsure if that's my problem

Comment: There are many different ways to search / sort an array. Search google for "javascript searching sorting algorithms" and test what works best for you. It is hard for us to help when you do not provide what your data structure looks like.

Comment: @Spangle Thoughts on if the reason my runtime is large is because "array" is being loaded when I do array[index]? Or is it because it is accessing index that makes it slow? Sorry, I'm not too familiar with good performance. If you believe it's because the accessing the index is making it slow, then yes I should manipulate the data somehow. But if its because the array is being loaded, I am unsure.

Comment: I suggest doing a test to see how long it is taking to load the array. Get the time it takes. After that, do another test to find out how much time it is taking to find the item in the array. Is the data from an api? Also javascript is single-threaded, something to consider. I.e you are not going to be searching the array, and loading it at the same time.

Comment: You really need to include a code snippet to get help here.

Comment: @Spangle My apologies. I have edited my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested different ways of looping through an `array` & it seems the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method is the most performant:

```
const array = [ 1, 2, 3];

for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  console.log(array[i]);  // 0.719ms
}

array.forEach(item => console.log(item)); // 0.236ms

array.map(item => console.log(item)); // 0.066ms

array.filter(item => console.log(item)); // 0.056ms
```

[image]

You can also use the [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method, which it's the faster, depending on your use-case.

```
array.sort(a => console.log(a)); // 0.046ms
```

Comment: Wow that's a great improvement of time! Is filtering letting the array load first, then go through it? And would you happen to know a method of breaking out of the array once an index is found? I think if that's possible, plus using the filter, would greatly improve runtime.

Comment: I do not really know on top of my head, but if I found out I will share it. Which index do you want to find & then stop the loop?

Comment: What exactly you want to do while looping through the `array` @webdesignnoob ? What kind of manipulation are you attempting?

Comment: @webdesignnoob you can also use [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), which is faster, but I don't know if it's useful for your use case. I'll update my answer to include as well.

Comment: I have updated my question with my code! I will try the methods you mentioned and see.